# Mongoose .save() returns empty error object, does not save in DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I am trying to learn MongoDB and typescript but currently running into some issues when trying to create my first document.

When I make a post request from postman, I get "Sending request" for 5 seconds, then it times out and returns an empty error object:

```
{
    "message": {}
}
```

and the posted data is not saved in my mongoDB.

I first set up connection like this in my server:

```
mongoose.connect(<string> process.env.DB_CONNECTION, { useNewUrlParser: true}, () =>
    console.log("connected to DB!")
);
```

and get back the correct statement logged, so I am connected.

I have a model that looks like this:

```
import { model, Schema, Model, Document } from "mongoose";

export interface IUser extends Document {
    name: string,
}

const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: Schema.Types.String,
            required: true,
        },
    },
    <any> {timeStamps: true}
);

const User: Model<IUser> = model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);
export default User;
```

The problem could be in there, but I don’t think it is.

Then, here is my post request for the endpoint I call:

```
router.post('/add', async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<any> => {
    try {
        const user: IUser = new User({
            name: req.body.name
        });

        const savedUser: IUser = await user.save();

        res.status(200).json(savedUser);
    } catch (err: any) {
        res.status(500).json({message: err});
        console.log("There was an error");
    }
})
```

Here is where I believe the error is becuase every time the request gets stuck on awaiting the .save()

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: You're awaiting `name.save()` but the variable for the model is called `game`

Comment: @MontgomeryWatts My mistake. I am awaiting user.save(), but I had wrote the wrong variable in there when writing the question. I edited the code to fix this change.

Comment: Can you confirm you've connected to MongoDB properly? The [mongoose.connect](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-connect) function can take a callback where you can check if an error has occurred.

Comment: You were right there was an issue connecting. I believe my password was causing an issue because there were special characters in it and I was not encoding them. Thank you so much for your help. Put in an answer and I’ll make correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the initial database connection, the password contained characters that that weren't being encoded. One solution to encode special characters is to make use of the built-in [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function.