# mongodb with nodejs returns empty error when adding documents to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i got this error about 5 seconds after clicking send in postman:

```
{
    "message": {}
}
```

Where the error happens:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const post = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description
    });

    try {
        const savedPost = await post.save();
        res.json(savedPost);
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({message: err}); // here
    }

});
```

I got the connected to DB in the console.log (mongo is run by docker-compose)

```
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: test_db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

DB_CONNECTION=mongodb://admin:admin@mongodb:27017/test_db

```
mongoose.connect(
    process.env.DB_CONNECTION, 
    { 
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    },
    () => console.log('connected to DB!!!') // call back
);
```

Schema for post:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


// describe how the data looks
const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Posts', PostSchema)
```

However, when I update the DB_connection to :
DB_CONNECTION=mongodb://admin:admin@mongodb:27017 (removing the /test_db)
the problem is gone and i and perfectly adding document to mongodb (but not in the test_db)

anyone knows where the problem is?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What is the error?, looks like an auth/permissions issue.

Comment: I guess it would be auth permission error also... the error is empty...res.json({message: err}) gives {"message":{}}. I saw this really similar post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66403766/mongoose-save-returns-empty-error-object-does-not-save-in-db

Comment: i have some clue here.. when i change the connection string to DB_CONNECTION=mongodb://admin:admin@mongodb:27017 (without /test_db) it works. could anyone give a explanation why..

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a callbacks:

```
    post.save(function(err, obj) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: 'created!', data: obj });
    });
```

Comment: as expected, i got {} (as an err) . thanks for reply!